# Ring-theoretic riddle

Tags: riddle

You are given a ring for which 1+1=3 and 9/12=0. Yet this ring is not [trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_ring), quite the opposite. What is your answer?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain I would think that any ring (in some sense of the word?) that fits with the puzzle would work. (Of course, in the [typical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)), there is no such thing, since $1+1=3$ and $9=12\cdot 0$ describes the trivial ring only)

Comment: @MiloBrandt I guess I didn't phrase my comment clearly.  I was trying to point out that the OP doesn't actually ask a question.  It says, "You are given a ring..." and then asks, "What is your answer?".  It should either say something like, "Come up with a ring for which..." or it should ask something like, "What is the ring you were given?".

Comment: @MiloBrandt actually $9=12 \cdot 0$ works in any ring of characteristic 3. Whereas $\frac{9}{12} = 0$ does trivialize the ring in the typical sense because it requires 12 to be invertible.

Comment: The amount of downvotes on this question is appalling.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Have a look at the answers, and you will see that the question is phrased perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is:

> No, I'll not marry a stranger from the internet

The ring is

> An engagement ring (see hexomino's reasoning) - definitely not trivial!

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> The Circle of Life.

because

> 1+1=3 refers to a man and a woman coming together to make a man, woman and child. 9/12 refers to 'nine months' at which point a baby is 0.